# What does $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand they are domain and codomain.
But does $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$ mean cross product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , $\mathbb{R}^m$ ? or n*m matrix?

Comment: It usually means the $n+m$ dimensional space consisting of vectors of real numbers.

Comment: It is describing a function or an operator that takes two vectors, one from $\mathbb R^n$ and one from $\mathbb R^m$ and returns a vector in $\mathbb R^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about elements of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ they are in the form $(a,b)$ where a and b are real numbers.

Now, you can think in similar way about $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$. It will have elements of type $(u,v)$ where **u** is an $n$ tuple vector and **v** is an $m$ tuple vector.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, you are right, $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$ is the Cartesian product of topological spaces, which means the set of all $(x,y)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, which is practically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.